# Which scope should i use for binding DbContext with Ninject in WPF App

Tags: wpf, ninject, entity-framework-5

In a web project i would use the RequestScope when binding the DbContext to my real DB context. But in WPF should i go for singleton or transcient scope ? Does it really matter which one over the other i choose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your app I would start with `PerThreadScope`. That way you have one for the apps main thread and for each background thread. They are tracked by ninject and properly disposed. If your app gets complexer you can switch to `NamedScope` or `InCallScope` and thereby scope the db context per RootView.

Comment: I would just add in that `NamedScope` and `InCallScope` are from *namedscope extension* : https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki

Answer (score 0):

The reason you go with RequestScope in web apps, is that you don't want your DbContext instances to be left in the memory.

Same goes with WPF or desktop apps, but it can be more tricky, depending on how you use the data access components (the thing that uses DbContext). Mostly it can be set on a Transient scope, which is disposed when your screen is closed and goes away, e.g. if you're using it directly in your view model, once the view model is going away (another view is being displayed), setting both ViewModel and DbContext to Transient and disposing of the ViewModel will ensure that your DbContext is also properly disposed.

Comment: so basically i have only to dispose the instance provinded by Ninject (would be the repository that have the dbcontext injected into) ? I am not using MVVM since its only a simple server console interface.

Comment: Attention: ninject does not track transient objects! You would need to dispose the db context yourself if you use hadis solution!